# На чём можно сделать flash веб-сайт?

Tags: веб-программирование, flash, action

Помнится, были программы в свое время flash mx и т.п. Подскажите пожалуйста, на чём сейчас можно сделать flash веб-сайт? Интересуют бесплатные программы.

Comment: Флэш уже умер, не теряй время.

Comment: А как было удобно, рисуй что хочешь.

Comment: @Sevastopol' опытные создатели Flash-контента вряд ли согласятся...